# Vuetify how to add custom theme

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I used vue cli3 to create my project.

```
vue create my-project
```

then I add vuetify to my project.

```
vue add vuetify
```

then after I created a custom theme from vuetify theme generator.
now I want to add that theme to my project.

In the official documentation of vuetify adding a theme is like this

```
    Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#3f51b5',
    secondary: '#b0bec5',
    accent: '#8c9eff',
    error: '#b71c1c'
  }
})
```

But my `main.js` looks like this

```
import '@babel/polyfill'
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

In here there is nothing called **Vuetify**. So how can I add a custom theme in this project setup?

Comment: And for picking colors, you can use a color theme builder for Vuetify: https://lobotuerto.com/vuetify-color-theme-builder Vuetify 2 uses dark and light attributes, so the code you have changes a bit. The link provided generates code for the new Vuetify version.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using vue-cli 3 here :)
Look at your project, there is a folder called: **plugins**.

src >> plugins

In this folder you will find vuetify.js, here you can just specify the theme you want to use as the documentation says.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    theme: {
        primary: "#f44336",
        secondary: "#e57373",
        accent: "#9c27b0",
        error: "#f44336",
        warning: "#ffeb3b",
        info: "#2196f3",
        success: "#4caf50"
      }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It's there. =)